# Passing functions as a parameter in pytest

Tags: python, class, pytest, fixtures, parameterization

I need to pass function as arguments in pytest parametrization.
and need to call those functions inside test function. Is there any way to do it without using eval?

I have fixtures defined in conftest.py which returns object to classes(defined in helper.py)
I need to call the class methods(in helper.py) from the test function. I am passing the class name.methodname as parameters.

```
  Eg: 
@pytest.mar.parametrize('fun', ['class_a.function1()','class_b.function2()'])
   def test1(class_a, class_b): 
       eval(fun)
```

eval() makes call to classA.function1 and classB.function2
where class_a and Class_b are fixtues that returns object of ClassA and ClassB Respectively.

The above example works fine. But I need to replace eval with something better.

Is there a better way to do this?
Any help is appreciated!!!!

Comment: Pass it in as `fun` and call as `fun()`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in any function, just don't surround them with quotes. Here is an example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pytest


class ClassA:
    def function1(self):
        return "function1"


class ClassB:
    def function2(self):
        return "function2"


class_a = ClassA()
class_b = ClassB()


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "fun",
    [class_a.function1, class_b.function2],
)
def test1(fun):
    actual = fun()
    assert "function" in actual
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, functions behave like any other object. So you can use them as a regular parameter values (without calling them in `parametrize`)

```
@pytest.mar.parametrize('fun', [class_a.function1, class_b.function2])
def test1(fun): 
    fun()
```